# Inserting Data from multiple select to single row table database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I make a form like this

```
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="text" name="brand">
```

and there is a multiple choice select:

```
    <select name="cars" multiple required>
    <option value="Avanza">Avanza</option>
    <option value="Xenia">Xenia</option>
    <option value="Colt">Colt</option>
    </select>
```

after i get selected options, i have to pass them to a table in the database; table consists of 3 columns like this: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBSIJ.jpg` id, brand and cars. When I choose all of selected options like this : `https://i.stack.imgur.com/codXQ.jpg` then I pressed the submit button.
How to transform the data into this : `https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ixsY.jpg`
Can you help me, please..

this is a query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cars (id, brand,cars) VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[brand]','$_POST[cars]')";
```

Comment: To do that you need to loop through each element in $_POST[cars] and insert into database

also your code is vulnerable to sql injection, I strongly suggest you to use prepared statements.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя it is not what i mean sir, i want to send data to the database with different "cars" refers to what i choose in multiple selected option and same "id"&"brand".

Answer (score -1):

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$cars = $_POST['cars'];
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `brand`,`cars`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$brand."','".$cars."')");
```

Comment: so just copy and past query from question!

Comment: Perhaps you don't have seen my query carefully @NullPoiиteя

Comment: No i have see your query properly and it does the exact same op dont want to do And still the same answer it doesnt address the problem in question  even